# Deserialising a JSON array collection issues VB .NET

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, deserialization

Getting the following error

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException:
> 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
> into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[]' because the type
> requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix
> this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or
> change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g.
> not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array
> or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
> JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
> deserialize from a JSON object.

I have it working already on a loop with multiple selectToken's, but its kind of slow calling 50 odd of those. I'd like to speed it up.

I'm going to omit some of the value names since its quite long.

But lets say I have nested classes

**edit**: this is with the Newtonsoft JSON library

```vb
Public Class Orders
    Public recordSetTotal As Integer

    Public Class ordersList 'orders list is an array in the JSON data source
        Public Class orderDetails
            Public grandTotal As Single
            Public placedDate As String
        End Class
    
        Public Class address
            Public postcode As String
            Public addressLine() As String 'this is an array in the JSON data source
        End Class
    End Class
End Class
```

```vb
'orderData is the JSON string block
Dim ordersList As List(Of Orders) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Orders))(orderData)
```

`orderData` might look like this (I've snipped the json up for an example so may be error in the json, but shouldn't be in the source). I've only put 1 array entry for `ordersList` but it will have multiple and match `recordSetTotal`.

```json
{
   "recordSetTotal":10,
   "ordersList":[
      {
         "orderDetails":{
            "grandTotal":50.0000,
            "placedDate":"2022-12-25 12:00:00.000"
         },
         "addressLine":[
            "123 Fake St",
            "Somewhere",
            "ABG"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Would it better to break out some of the nesting so I can make `ordersList` an array?

```vb
Public Class Orders
    Public recordSetTotal As Integer
    Public ordersList() as ordersList
End Class

Public Class ordersList 'orders list is an array in the JSON data source
    Public Class orderDetails
        Public grandTotal As Single
        Public placedDate As String
    End Class
    
    Public Class address
        Public postcode As String
        Public addressLine() As String 'this is an array in the JSON data source
    End Class
End Class
```

And If I was going to de-nest the classes, should the array be like this:

```vb
Public ordersList() as ordersList
```

or this:

```vb
Public ordersList as ordersList()
```

Comment: You are deserializing to `(Of List(Of Orders))` when it looks like your json contains only one `Orders`, so you should be deserializing to `(Of Orders)`. Then, your `Orders` class only has one field, `recordSetTotal`, and does not have a property to contain the `ordersList`. The definition of a nested class does not create a property in the parent class. There must be something like `public property ordersList as List(of ordersList)` in `Orders`, and then the `ordersList` class does not contain any properties either.

Comment: Thank you I think I've gotten it working with that. Remove the of list on both sides. Move ordersList as a separate class, set it in the orders class exactly as you wrote and         Dim test As Orders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Orders)(json)
seems to pull it up

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a root class, your classes should be

```
 Public Class Root
        Public Property recordSetTotal As Integer
        Public Property ordersList As OrdersList()
    End Class

  Public Class OrdersList
        Public Property orderDetails As OrderDetails
        Public Property addressLine As String()
    End Class

Public Class OrderDetails
        Public Property grandTotal As Double
        Public Property placedDate As String
    End Class
```

and code

```
Dim ordersList As List(Of Orders) = JsonConvert
                                   .DeserializeObject(Of Root)(orderData).ordersList
```

Answer (score -1):

So in case anyone else was wondering, check the commennt left by GSerg on my post.

All the classes have to be un-nested. And everything inside the class must be a public property, including objects from outside classes.

An array must be public property ordersList as List(of ordersList) for example rather than public property ordersList() as ordersList

Than reading the json is as simple as
Dim deserialised As Orders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Orders)(json)

Any json keys/fields that dont have a matching name as a public property wont be read into the results obviously.

Comment: The classes don't have to be un-nested. The rest is correct.